# how to hide/show stl model with the checkbox in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to hide/show stl file with the toggle in checkbox.
Thank you in advance. I have tried scene.remove(outerstl);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the property [Object3D.visible](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.visible) in order to control visibility for an arbitrary 3D object. It's not necessary to remove the object from the scene.

Comment: thank you for your response but i am using STLloader so that i could load my stl file

Comment: `STLLoader` returns a geometry than you can use to create a `Mesh`. A `Mesh` is also an `Object3D`. See the official example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ba4489ded66212ac9e6d3017a6bb856023bd026f/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html#L93-L97